# The space $ \left( \sum \ell_p^n \right)_2$ is reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\ell_p^n:= (\mathbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_p)$. I want to show that the space $$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell_p^n \right)_2 := \left(\left\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} : x_n \in  \ell_p^n  \right\},\|\cdot\|_2 \right)$$ is reflexive. Here the $2$-norm of some $(x_n) \in \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell_p^n \right)_2 $ is $$ \left\|(x_n)\right\|_2:= \left\|\left(\|x_n\|_p\right)_{n \in \mathbb N}\right\|_2. $$

Obviously all the $\ell_p^n$ are reflexive as there are finite-dimensional.

Comment: You could try to find the dual space, and then the double dual (this will be what you guess); or think about uniform convexity.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the first hint tomorrow. My goal is to find a reflexive space which does not admit an equivalent uniform convex norm. I  showed that the given space is not superreflexive, uniform convexity is a super-property and milmans theorem. To complete the proof, I need to show it is reflexive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a general fact that the dual of $\left(\oplus_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right)_2$ is $\left(\oplus_{n=1}^\infty X_n^*\right)_2$, with the natural pairing: 
$(x_n^*)$ acts on $(x_n)$ by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^*(x_n)$. The proof is basically the same as the proof that the dual of $\ell_2$ is $\ell^2$:

1. The pairing is well-defined, using Cauchy-Schwarz.
2. Given a continuous functional $\phi$ on $\left(\oplus_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right)_2$, let $x_n^*$ denote its restriction to $X_n$. Observe that $\sum\|x_n^*\|^2<\infty$.
3. Note  that $\phi$ agrees with $(x_n^*)$ on the dense subspaced formed by the sequences where all but finitely many elements are zero.
4. By continuity, $\phi$ agrees with $(x_n^*)$ everywhere.

From the general fact it follows that the $\ell_2$ sum of any family of reflexive spaces (and in particular, of any finite dimensional spaces) is reflexive.

Naturally, in your example you need $p=1$ or $p=\infty$ to obtain a non-superreflexive example.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the kind of result I was hoping for. I took the case where $p=\infty$. I was looking for a result like that in some books, but I did not find anything helpful. Do you have any suggestion where I can find this result (to cite it).

Comment: @J.B. I think _Introduction to the theory of Banach spaces_ by Megginson should have it. That book does not go far into theory, but presents basic results in much detail.

Comment: There is the same statement for finite direct sums, thank you. I am having troubles to show $ \sum \|x_n^*\|^2 < \infty $ in step 2 though. Assuming otherwise, we find $x_n \in X_n$, such that $ \sum (x_n^*(x_n))^2 = \infty $, but this is not a contradiction, since $(x_n)$ may not be in ($\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb N} X_n)_2$.

Comment: For infinite products it's stated on page 77 of Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*, but only as an exercise (no proof). The difficulty you are facing is the same that one faces when proving that $\ell_2^*=\ell^2$: how to show that the sequence representing a linear functional is in $l^2$? Answer: use truncated sequence $x_n$ (ending with zeros) to contradict the *boundedness* of linear functional $(x_n^*)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to finish the proof now :)